# Is atomicity maintained in MongoDB GridFS for CRUD operations?

Tags: mongodb, crud, gridfs, atomic

As GridFS stores data chunks in `fs.chunks` and metadata in `fs.files`. So, in a single transaction it manages two collections. Is atomicity guaranteed for all CRUD operations?

Comment: I am a certified MongoDB DBA and to be honest with you: I don't know for sure. I am pretty confident about C,R and D. Regarding U, I have to research, since atomicity is guaranteed only on a document level. Please have a bit of patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the [MongoDB FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#when-should-i-use-gridfs) says:

> Do not use GridFS if you need to update the content of the entire file atomically. As an alternative you can store multiple versions of each file and specify the current version of the file in the metadata. You can update the metadata field that indicates “latest” status in an atomic update after uploading the new version of the file, and later remove previous versions if needed.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that this means that MongoDB does not just not guarantee consistency for `fs.chunks` and `fs.files` but not the consistency of the chunks of one file in `fs.chunks` either.

Comment: @Philipp  : Suppose I am saving name as metadata. Now I want to update the name. Do I need to update whole file again just for name ?

Comment: @dev When you are just updating the metadata, why would you update anything else?

Comment: @Philipp my bad...I was confused. I checked java driver again. I can update metadata easily. Thanks for your help......:)